# hibernate can't configure POJO by *.hbm.xml

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, entity, configure

I'm new to hibernate and I wrote a simply bean: `User`. Although I can configure it directly using `configuration.addResource("User.hbm.xml")` in my java code, but when I configure it through `hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```
<hibernate-configuration>

<session-factory>

    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">1234</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool(use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">none</property>

    <!-- List of XML mappings -->
    <mapping resource="User.hbm.xml"/>

</session-factory>
```

The application does not configure `User` entity and it runs with the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.philip.fin.test.User
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:781)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1520)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:100)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:679)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:671)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:666)
at com.philip.fin.test.TestHibernate.main(TestHibernate.java:37)
```

the User.hbm.xml file pasted below:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
     <class name="com.philip.fin.test.User" table="User_table" catalog="test">
         <id name="userId" column="User_Id">
             <generator class="increment"/>
         </id>
         <property name="userName" column="User_Name" type="string"/>
         <property name="userMessage" column="User_Message type="string"/>
      </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: What is the location of your `User.hbm.xml` file relative to the config file?

Comment: the same path, I put them both in src/main/resources/ directory. And the User.java file is under: com.philip.fin.test package。

Comment: @PengChen: share your user.hbm.xml file

Comment: I think you are using maven and you might have put your User.java inside your test folder instead of main?

Comment: @aksappy, I know there are main folder and test folder, but I certainly have put the User.java in main folder.

Comment: @Vaibs, I paste the user.hbm.xml file below:<hibernate-mapping> <class name="com.philip.fin.test.User" table="User_table" catalog="test"> <id name="userId" column="User_Id"> <generator class="increment"/> </id> <property name="userName" column="User_Name" type="string"/> <property name="userMessage" column="User_Message type="string"/> </class> </hibernate-mapping>

Comment: I think my User.hbm.xml file is right, because I can use configuration.addResource() to use it correctly from application. So seems the app didn't get the User.hbm.xml。